# Can I use "$first" operator on two fields in a "$group" operation in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the dataset

```
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "aaa" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "exam", "score" : 54.6535436362647 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "bbb" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 31.95004496742112 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "ccc" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 14.8504576811645 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "ddd" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 63.98402553675503 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "eee" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "exam", "score" : 74.20010837299897 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "fff" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 96.76851542258362 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "ggg" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 21.33260810416115 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "hhh" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 44.31667452616328 }
```

Say, for each student, I need to find minimum score and the corresponding document_id(_id).

Here is my pipeline

```
pipeline = [
{"$sort":{"student_id":1,"score":1 } },
{"$group": {"_id":"$student_id","mscore":{"$first":"$score"},"docid":{"$first":"$_id"} } },
{"$sort":{"_id":1}}, 
{"$project":{"docid":1,"_id":0}}
]
```

While this is working fine, I am not sure whether it is because I have the right query or whether it is because of way data is stored.

Here is my stragery

> Sort by student_id, score
>   Group by student_id and do first on score, it will give student_id, min_score

Now, I need the doc_id(_id) also for this min_score, so I am using first on that field also. Is that correct?

Let's say after the sort, I need the entire first document, so should I apply first on each and every field or is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the entire first document after sorting, apply the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) operator on the system variable [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) which references the root document, i.e. the top-level document, currently being processed in the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator pipeline stage. Your pipeline would look like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$sort": { "score": 1 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$student_id",
            "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$data._id",
            "student_id": "$data.student_id",
            "type": "$data.type",
            "lowest_score": "$data.score"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Is using first on multiple fields also correct like the way I have done in the question? meaning will it give me what I am looking for?

Comment: @Dude Yes, it will give the same results.